# Authentication for multiple Web Applications without changing code of the applications

Tags: authentication, jwt, http-headers, single-sign-on, reverse-proxy

We host a variety of web applications written and maintained by different departments. Currently each of these applications has its own authentication/authorization, which is confusing to our customers. We now want to unify the authentication/authorization for all the web apps, but without having to alter the code of every application. We want to build a simple dashboard from where the customers can access the applications.

The best solution we came up with was a reverse proxy with sub request authentication.

We build the dashboard and a login page with a jwt authentication in the backend. When an application is accessed from the dashboard, we include the jwt in a header, and the proxy does a sub request to the backend to check if the user is allowed to access the application. But this only works for simple html pages and not for our applications, because after the initial page is loaded the applications start to do their own requests for images, css, etc. and there the jwt header is missing so the requests fail at the reverse proxy.

Is there an alternative to using a reverse proxy, or something we are missing, to make this work?